# Success Callback on Backbone Destroy Function Does Not Fire

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  My success and error callbacks are not firing and I am returning a JSON response from the server. Any ideas on where I am screwing up?

```
mysite.city.delete_photo = {
    "Model": Backbone.Model.extend({
        "id": "deletePhoto",
        "initialize": function initialize(id) {
            this.url = "/assets/ajax/delete_image.php?img_id=" + id;
        }
    }),
    "View": Backbone.View.extend({
        "initialize": function initialize(id) {
            _.bindAll(this,
                "render",
                "success");

            this.model = new mysite.city.delete_photo.Model(id);

            this.render();
        },
        "render": function render() {
            this.model.destroy({
                "cache": false,
                "success": this.success,
                "error": this.error
            });
        },
        "success": function success(model, data) {
            console.log("test");
        },
        "error": function error() {
            message('error', 'This image could not be deleted.');
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: Indentation. Definitely indentation. :)

Comment: My coding style works.  It's not the indentation that's messing it up.

Comment: I was kidding. My reading of the docs gives no hint of success and error attributes for the View class. Maybe you can add a 'sync' attribute to the model, and pass your error and success handlers in to it as options?

Answer (score 0):

`success` or `error` is not a function in Model, but both are callbacks for Model's fetch and save methods. you could fire success or error event when fetching with blow code:

```
model.fetch({success: function(model, response, options) {
    console.log('success triggered');
});
```

same logic with `error` callback.

Comment: I would disagree.  You should be able to have success and error callbacks in the destroy function http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-destroy

Comment: you are right, a lot methods in a Model have the success and error call back such as destroy method. it is the same logic how destroy method to fire success or error as model.fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Following line

```
this.model = new mysite.city.delete_photo.Model(id);
```

Should be:

```
this.model = new mysite.city.delete_photo.Model({'id':id});
```

In the first case `Id` is not set to the model at all and and the  `destroy` returns false without even sending a `DELETE` request to the server since the the model does not have `ID` and is consider as `new`.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy